# Can't get HQ favicon for my blog

Tags: image-processing, favicon

I have some HQ images that I'd like to use one of them as my favicon, and I've turned them into icons using this online converter:

https://realfavicongenerator.net/

But the result is too blurry no matter what output I tried. I read somewhere that Blogger turns uploaded images for favicons into 16x16 by default, which is a low resolution.

I'm sorry for not being able to link my blog as it's private.

Any suggestions how to keep it in HQ?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: If you can read a bit of HTML: look at the source of your page and look for the string "ico". You should find the URL of the favicon Blogger generated for you (probably something like "/img/favicon.ico"). Open this URL in a new tab and look at its resolution (Chrome displays this in the tab name). If it is 16x16 whereas you submitted a high resolution icon to Blogger, chances are that it scales down images without letting you choose...

Comment: Yes, sadly it's scaled down to 16x16 but I thought there's a workaround for this kind of issue in Blogger.

Comment: I don't know Blogger so I can't certify it behaves that way. Only an hypothesis. This is why I responded with a comment and not with a genuine answer. Maybe there is a workaround...